# How to reuse the same <tr> tag in html table on jsp page

Tags: html, jsp, jstl, html-table, jsp-tags

I have html table inside of jsp page. My code looks like this:

```
<c:choose>    
    <c:when test="${empty institutionAttributes}">      
        <h2 align="center"><spring:message code="label.attributes.msg"/> </h2>      
    </c:when>

    <c:otherwise>
        <h3 align="center"><spring:message code="label.result.msg"/> </h3>      
        <table border="1" align="center">               
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th align="center"><spring:message code="label.header.table.name" /></th>
                <th align="center"><spring:message code="label.header.table.type" /></th>
                <th align="center"><spring:message code="label.header.table.date" /></th>
                <th align="center"><spring:message code="label.header.table.dayscheduale" /></th>
                <th align="center"><spring:message code="label.header.table.workscheduale" /></th>
                <th align="center"><spring:message code="label.header.table.rotation" /></th>
                <th align="center"><spring:message code="label.header.table.numberkids" /></th>
                <th align="center"><spring:message code="label.header.table.under3" /></th>
                <th align="center"><spring:message code="label.header.table.upper3" /></th>
                <th align="center"><spring:message code="label.header.table.goschool" /> <br> <fmt:formatDate value="${formDescriptionVar.kidsGoSchoolDate}" pattern="yyyy"/>  <spring:message code="label.header.table.year" /></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>                 
            <c:forEach items="${institutionAttributes}" var="institutionVar">
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">${institutionVar.nameOfInstitution}</td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>

            <c:forEach items="${institutionTypeAttributes}" var="institutionTypeVar">
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">${institutionTypeVar.typeOfInstitution}</td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>

            <c:forEach items="${formDateAttributes}" var="formDateVar">
                <tr>
                    <td align="center"><fmt:formatDate value="${formDateVar.particularDate}" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy"/>  </td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>

            <c:forEach  items="${formDescriptionAttributes}" var="formDescriptionVar">
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">${formDescriptionVar.daySchedule}</td>
                    <td align="center">${formDescriptionVar.workScheduale}</td>
                    <td align="center">${formDescriptionVar.rotation}</td>
                    <td align="center">${formDescriptionVar.numberOfKids}</td>
                    <td align="center">${formDescriptionVar.kidsUnder3YearsOld}</td>
                    <td align="center">${formDescriptionVar.kidsUpper3YearsOld}</td>
                    <td align="center">${formDescriptionVar.kidsGoSchoolNumber}</td>            
                 </tr>
            </c:forEach>
            </tr>           

        </tbody>

        </table>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Inside of JSP page I have table with `<thead>` and `<tbody>` tags.

Inside of `<tbody>` I use JSP's `<c:forEach>` tag.

Inside of `<c:forEach>` I use `<tr>` and `<td>`tags.

In pictures I want:

```
|------------------------------------|
|  Header1  |  Header2  |  Header3   |
|------------------------------------|
|   Value1  |  Value2   |  Value3    |
|------------------------------------|
```

What I get:

```
 |------------------------------------|
 |  Header1  |  Header2  |  Header3   |
 |------------------------------------|
 |   Value1  |           |            |
 |------------------------------------|
 |           |  Value2   |            |
 |------------------------------------|
 |           |           |   Value3   | 
 |------------------------------------|
```

So, the problem is that `<c:forEach>` create new `<tr>` inside every `<c:forEach>`, but what I need is to use the **same** `<tr>` in different `<c:forEach>`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Or I didn't understand your question properly, or your problem has a very easy solution.

You just need to put the `<tr>` tag outside the `forEach`, for example:

```
<tr>
  <c:forEach items="${institutionAttributes}" var="institutionVar">
    <td align="center">${institutionVar.nameOfInstitution}</td>
  </c:forEach>
</tr>
```

This will create only 1 row in the table, with 1 column for each value in `institutionAttributes`...

Once the `foreach` is processed, your HTML will look like:

```
<tr>
  <td align="center">nameOfInstitution1</td>
  <td align="center">nameOfInstitution2</td>
  <td align="center">nameOfInstitution3</td>
  ...
</tr>
```

Comment: @user2547487, I still think what you need to do is what I explained... did you try it?

Comment: Sir. It will put nameofInstitution 1, 2, 3 in each row, will srart it form new row. I don't want it to be like this. I need to put nameofInstitution1 and nameofInstitution2 and nameofInstitution3 to one row. Like in my picture above, what I want...

Comment: @user2547487, with my code you'll have `nameofInstitution1`, `nameofInstitution2` and `nameofInstitution3` as 3 caloumns in a **single row**! It is indeed what you're looking for... You can see the resulting code, which clearly shows **1 row** (`<tr>...</tr>`) with **3 cells** (`<td>...</td>`)

Comment: Sir. We don't understand each other. I tried how you suggested to me. You see the problem is that I don't know how many objects inside of attribute I will have. And I need to iterate over them. And nameOfInstitution this is property inside of institutionVar. This is what I want to render, but what is <td align="center">nameOfInstitution1,2,3</td> I did not expect it.?